# Spring artifactDescriptorException

Tags: java, spring-mvc, maven-2

Hi I am a newbie to Spring, on STS modifing the autogenerated spring mvc project, I get this error on the markers view:

```
    Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework:spring-context:jar:${spring.version}: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.springframework:spring-context:pom:${spring.version} from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework:spring-context:pom:${spring.version} from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Illegal character in path at index 72: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-context/${spring.version}/spring-context-${spring.version}.pom    pom.xml /MMASGIS7   line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
```

you can see my pom.xml  at http://pastebin.com/DkKzG2DR
can you address me on the right direction to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maven runtime isnt able to resolve the dependency because, it isnt able to resolve the version that you have specified since the property is missing. 
Add this property to the pom.xml file or remove the `spring.version` completely and use the `org.springframework-version` that you already have defined in your pom.

```
<spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
```

I would suggest use just one of them for consistency and transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You are using two properties for same purpose: i.e. 
`org.springframework-version` and `spring.version` . Use only one of them, refer the same in rest of the pom part.

```
              <properties>
                        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
                        <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
                              or    
                        <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
                        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
                        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>                       
                </properties>


Since you have alreay defined `org.springframework-version` , You can replace ${spring.version} by ${org.springframework-version}
```